# Appium and Virtual Android Device desired capabilities: SessionNotCreatedException error

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

So I am trying to write an automation test script for an android app running inside an Android Emulator (avd) but I am getting the error below in Appium logs:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect.
 We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities
","capabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapab
ilities","requiredCapabilities","capabilities","alwaysMatch","firstMatch"]
```

My setup is:

1. Android Studio 162 (w/ sdk, note that this latest version does not include the 'android' command anymore, the creation of the android virtual device is done through Tools > Android > AVD Manager)
2. IntelliJ 2016.3.5 (for writing the automation test script)
3. selenium-java 3.3.0 (required jar)
4. appium java client 4.1.2 (required jar)
5. appium server 1.6.3 (executed in nodejs cli by running 'appium')
6. Android Virtual Device version 5.1 Lollipop

Running 'adb devices' command in cmd gives me

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Desired capabilities setting is

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", path_to_apk);
    driver =  new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

}
```

IDE error output when running the test:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=src//main//resources//test.apk, platformVersion=5.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=emulator-5554}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5b41', time: '2017-03-07 19:26:04 +0000'
```

I am stuck at this point and don't know what to do.

Comment: Please be aware that the device name is not "emulator-5554" - This is the devices udid.

Comment: Managed to fix this issue by using Selenium-Java 3.0.1

Comment: @jeffsia any update ? did you figured out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned in my comment that I ultimately used an older version of Selenium in order for the desired capabilities to match what is expected by Appium 1.6.3. In my case it's Selenium Java Client 3.0.1 + Appium 1.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get it working with selenium 3.0.1, like OP did. I'm using selenium grid with appium. What eventually worked for me was using appium@1.6.4-beta, which works with selenium up to 3.1.0 version.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that there are certain combinations of appium and selenium versions that we have to consider for compatibility. In my case, it's Appium 1.6.3 and Selenium Java Client version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
```

Above exception only occurred when we are not able to established between appium and mobile device.

There might be chances that apk path is wrong as it is showing in logs `app=src//main//resources//test.apk` but it should be path of directory where it store like `c://mobile//apk//test.apk` please correct it.

Also you have not mention **appPackage** and **appActivity** in your **DesiredCapabilities** like below.

```
// specify the application package that we copied from appium

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.testapp");

    // specify the application activity that we copied from appium

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".HomeScreenActivity");
```

Above parameter required when you have already install .apk on your device. It always good to include these capabilities while creating session.

please let me know if it doesn't work for you.